# Youtube identify its installed app: how?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Have you try to install the youtube app and then open in safari mobile one url like http://www.youtube.com/cocacola

On the top of the page Youtube tell me that I have already installed the youtube app....

How it is made?

It could be the solution to open an app from the url with the detection of installed app.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pre-iOS 6, looks like their website hardcodes a banner when you visit it. You can see it in Safari on Mac if you set your user agent to an iPxx agent (in the Developer menu.)

For iOS 6, they use a meta tag introduced by Apple: `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE">`. If you view the page source, you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Smart App Banner (link to Apple’s Safari documentation)](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).

You can implement them as such `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">`. The affiliate-data and app-argument are optional.